# Problem with integrating Facebook in my application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook

The message which is to posted on the wall of Facebook is automatically open without clicking the Facebook tab.

Here is the code which shows a message to be posted on the wall of Facebook.

```
- (void)postToWall {
    FBStreamDialog *dialog = [[[FBStreamDialog alloc] init] autorelease];
    dialog.userMessagePrompt = @"Enter your message:";
    dialog.attachment = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"name\":\"Facebook Connect for iPhone\",\"href\":\"http://developers.facebook.com/connect.php?tab=iphone\",\"caption\":\"Caption\",\"description\":\"Description\",\"media\":[{\"type\":\"image\",\"src\":\"http://img40.yfrog.com/img40/5914/iphoneconnectbtn.jpg\",\"href\":\"http://developers.facebook.com/connect.php?tab=iphone/\"}],\"properties\":{\"another link\":{\"text\":\"Facebook home page\",\"href\":\"http://www.facebook.com\"}}}"];
    [dialog show];
}
```

Comment: somebody align this code

Comment: arrange the so that I can see. and also check whether you have called up the method when application launching so it may be posting or called without clicking on face book tab.???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are calling the `postToWall()` function somewhere in the code. Call this function only when the Facebook tab is clicked. (Just put in a breakpoint and check.)